# When trying to apply a simple function I am getting this error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item()...."

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with tick data that is below and I am trying to apply a simple function that will allow me to compare whether or not the last price was at the bid or ask and thus representing aggressive buying or selling. However when I apply the function I receive the error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evlDk.jpg)

```
def VD(x):
  if x > ES_Data['Bid']:
    result = ES_Data['Volume']
  else:
    result = (ES_Data['Volume']*-1)
  return result
```

I have tried using a lambda function instead but am getting the same error. I have been messing around with this for a couple hours now and have made no progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in this if statement `if x > ES_Data['Bid']` the result of `x > ES_Data['Bid']` is a False/True series comparing the given `x` to the each element in `ES_Data['Bid']`. That is why you are getting the error telling you that the if statement is being applied to a full series.

If you are trying to apply this to all rows, you could do something like this:

```
result = ES_Data['Volume'] * np.where(x > ES_Data['Bid'], 1, -1)
```

the np.where will return a full array of 1s where the condition is met and -1s where the condition is False.

Putting that in a function will look like this:

```
def VD(x):
  return ES_Data['Volume'] * np.where(x > ES_Data['Bid'], 1, -1)
```